# Re-rendering styles in React (onClick, turn div background from red to blue)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following very simple React Class:

```
import React from "react"

let color = 'red';

export default class DoubleClick extends React.Component {  
  handleClick() {
    console.log("Hi");
    color = 'blue';
  }
  handleDoubleClick() {
    console.log("Double Click");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>
          <div onClick={this.handleClick} style={{backgroundColor: color}}> 
            <span onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}> Hello </span> 
            <span onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}> world. </span>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to change the background color of the `div`, when the `div` is clicked. What would be the best approach to do this with React? I have defined a color variable outside of the class, but I am aware that this is probably not the right approach. Also, it is not working or re-rendering, although the `console.log` does work and the function is called.

Comment: To complement the answers given, here are some docs about state in react: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working beacuse you did not bind `this` to your function so, a **function** way of doing such a thing is to use a changable state:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class DoubleClick extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    };
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Hi');
    this.setState({ style: { color: 'blue' } });
  }

  handleDoubleClick() {
    console.log('Double Click');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} style={this.state.style}>
          <span onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick.bind(this)}> Hello </span>
          <span onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick.bind(this)}> world. </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

edited: 
Fixing the state management.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your color in Component's state and toggle it on clicks.

```
import React from "react"

export default class DoubleClick extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color: 'red',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>
          <div onClick={() => this.setState({ color: 'blue'})} style={{backgroundColor: color}}> 
            <span onDoubleClick={() => this.setState({ color: 'red'})}> Hello </span> 
            <span onDoubleClick={() => this.setState({ color: 'red'})}> world. </span>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your color in the `state` edit the state on `click` and use the `state` in your DOM.

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state{
    color:"red" //initial value
  }
  
  onClick(){
   this.setState({
    color:"blue";
   })
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div onClick={() => this.onClick()} style={{color:this.state.color}}>test</div>
  }
}
```